# Problem in installing Ubuntu 11.10 and 10.04 in mac using CD

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, mac

i have a macbook air (late 2008) 
I burned the ubuntu iso file (32 bit )to a blank 700mb cd using disk utility (the proper way) 
When i booted into the cd i got a black screen then a black screen with ubuntu logo and 4 options :- "Try without install" "install" "Check disk for errors " "boot from 1st hard drive " 
Which ever option i choose makes my mac reboot back to my initial hard drive 
I really want ubuntu but am not able to install it :/  
What am i doing wrong?? 
Please help 
P.S-i tried the following things with both the softwares (11.10 and 10.04) 
 and i am not able to make a bootable pen drive 
btw i downloaded the iso from the official site ,the download said it is 695 mb but it was 729 mb (Is there something wrong with this? )

Comment: Don't press any keys when the disc is booting. This will take you with a livecd. See if that works.

Comment: That doesnt work at all 
it makes the situation worse

Answer (score 1):

did you download the +mac cd image?

That is not the one you download from the frontpage FYI, you have to go into a mirror to choose it.

Fx:
http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/oneiric/release/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso

Notice the +mac at the end. This basically makes sure the mac boots with legacy bios instead of EFI.

Bootable USB stick does normally never work, I have been unsuccessful with all the guides that claim it works.

Comment: Hey 
Thanx 
Hope it works
can you please give me the link to 32 bit version for mac ?

Comment: I downloaded the iso with the "+mac" at the end and its still the same
<br>
What to do ? Plz help